# Collectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath not call after reload

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift

i have 2 dictionary and dictionary contain array of passing in  numberOfItemsInSection

**1.** `self.dicMyClaimsSender`

**2.** `self.dicMyClaimsReceiver`

I am using segment control. When I tap on segment, then I reload the collectionView (I am using 3 collection view).

```
// UISegmentedControl method
@IBAction func segmntAction(sender:UISegmentedControl) {

        switch segmnetCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0:

            self.isSenderSelected = true
            self.heightCollection.constant  = 130.0
            self.heightViewImg.constant     = 0.0
            self.heightViewVideo.constant   = 0.0
            self.heightViewFile.constant    = 0.0
            self.heightBtnAttach.constant   = 42.0
            self.heightBtnSendFile.constant = 42.0
            self.collectionImg.reloadData()
            self.collectionFile.reloadData()
            self.collectionVideo.reloadData()

            break

        case 1:

            self.isSenderSelected = false
            self.heightViewImg.constant     = 156.0
            self.heightViewVideo.constant   = 156.0
            self.heightViewFile.constant    = 156.0
            self.heightCollection.constant  = 0.0
            self.heightBtnAttach.constant   = 0.0
            self.heightBtnSendFile.constant = 0.0

            self.collectionImg.reloadData()
            self.collectionFile.reloadData()
            self.collectionVideo.reloadData()
            break
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

// MARK: - UICollectionView Delegates & Datasources

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isSenderSelected {
            if collectionView.tag == 1 {
                return self.assets?.count ?? 0
            } else if collectionView.tag == 2 {
                if self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Images.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewImg.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewImg.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Images.count
            } else if collectionView.tag == 3 {
                if self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Video.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewVideo.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewVideo.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Video.count
            } else {
                if self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Document.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewFile.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewFile.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsSender.ary_Document.count
            }
        } else {
            if collectionView.tag == 2 {
                if self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Images.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewImg.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewImg.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Images.count
            } else if collectionView.tag == 3 {
                if self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Video.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewVideo.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewVideo.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Video.count
            } else {
                if self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Document.count == 0 {
                    self.heightViewFile.constant = 0.0
                } else {
                    self.heightViewFile.constant = 156.0
                }
                return self.dicMyClaimsReceiver.ary_Document.count
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For each segment you have taken different collection view ?

Comment: i am also trying to as you say but not working boss

Comment: can you show the code of when you calling reload method?

Comment: @BhaveshBarot have you assigned delegate and datasource for UICollectionView ?

Comment: @KTang i am recalling collection view in segment button i already added on the Top. Please this method 
func segmntAction(sender:UISegmentedControl)

Comment: @K.R.Saravana Kumar yes boss i am assigned delegate and datasource

Comment: Be sure the number of item is not 0.

Comment: @无夜之星辰  Yes boss number of item is not 0.

Comment: Check your storyboard/xib file be sure it's connected to your properties. Your code seems no problem. So try to connect them again.